# this operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, this

Suppose I have JavaScript code like

```
      myClass = function(){
          function doSomething(){
              alert(this); // this1 
          }
      } 
      alert(this); //this2
```

What those two 'this' objects are refer for??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `this` value in the global execution context, refers to the global object, e.g.:

```
this === window; // true
```

For Function Code, it really depends on how do you invoke the function, for example, the `this` value is implicitly set when:

**Calling a function with no *base object* reference**:

```
myFunc();
```

The `this` value will also refer to the global object.

**Calling a function bound as a property of an object**:

```
obj.method();
```

The `this` value will refer to `obj`.

**Using the `new` operator**:

```
new MyFunc();
```

The `this` value will refer to a newly created object that inherits from `MyFunc.prototype`.

Also, you can set explicitly that value when you invoke a function, using either the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply) methods, for example:

```
function test(arg) {
  alert(this + arg);
}
test.call("Hello", " world!"); // will alert "Hello World!"
```

The difference between `call` and `apply` is that with `apply`, you can pass correctly any number of arguments, using an Array or an `arguments` object, e.g.:

```
function sum() {
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    result += arguments[i];
  }
  return result;
}

var args = [1,2,3,4];
sum.apply(null, args); // 10

// equivalent to call
sum(1,2,3,4); // 10
```

If the first argument value of `call` or `apply` is `null` or `undefined`, the `this` value will refer to the global object.

<sub>(note that this will change in the future, with ECMAScript 5, where `call` and `apply` pass the `thisArg` value without modification)</sub>