# JavaScript: Access own Object Property inside Array Literal

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, unobtrusive-javascript

Given an Array Literal inside a JavaScript Object, accessing its own object's properties does not seem to work:

```
 var closure =  {

         myPic : document.getElementById('pic1'),
         picArray: [this.myPic]
 }    

 alert(closure.picArray[0]); // alerts [undefined]
```

Whereas declaring an Array Item by accessing an other JavaScript Object seem to work

```
 ​var closure1 = {
 ​    
 ​     myPic : document.getElementById('pic1')
 ​}
 ​    
 ​var closure2 =  {
 ​  
 ​        picArray: [closure1.myPic]
 ​}    
 ​    
 ​alert(closure2.picArray[0]); // alerts [object HTMLDivElement]
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5pmDG/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `this` value will not work like that, it refers to a value determined by the actual execution context, not to your object literal.

If you declare a function member of your object for example, you could get the desired result:

```
var closure =  {
  myPic: document.getElementById('pic1'),
  getPicArray: function () {
    return [this.myPic];
  }
};
//...
closure.getPicArray();
```

Since the `this` value, inside the `getPicArray` function, will refer to your `closure` object.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320677/this-operator-in-javascript/3320706#3320706) to another question, where I explain the behavior of the `this` keyword.

**Edit:** In response to your comment, in the example that I've provided, the `getPicArray` method will generate a new Array object each time it is invoked, and since you are wanting to store the array and make changes to it, I would recommend you something like this, construct your object in two steps:

```
var closure =  {
  myPic: document.getElementById('pic1')
};
closure.picArray = [closure.myPic];
```

Then you can modify the `closure.picArray` member without problems.

Comment: Thanks! Excellent answer. How would you then modify the array persistently?

Comment: @Stephan, Thank you!. With my second example, you can simply use the `picArray` property, e.g. `closure.picArray.push("foo");`

Answer (score 2):

The `this` property does not point to the `closure` object. If we were to define the myPic property on the global scope, then you will see `picArray` initialized with that value. Consider this example:

```
<script>
window.myPic = "Global myPic";

var closure =  {
    myPic : document.getElementById('pic1'),
    picArray: [this.myPic] // this refers to the global object
};

console.log(closure.picArray); // ["Global myPic"];
</script>
```

`this` is one of the hardest concepts in JavaScript. You might like this [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) on the topic.