# How to pass javascript object value to its "child" object

Tags: javascript, inheritance, javascript-objects

I'm trying to pass a variable to a child object of my parent object, but its returning undefined. (clearly I'm not sure how the scoping of a JS object works).

```
var parent = {
    pid: '565',
    child: {
       cid: this.pid + '_child_789',
       sayHello: function(){
          alert('My id is ' + this.cid);
       }
    }
}
```

Calling `parent.child.sayHello()` logs the `this.cid` as undefined.

I'm (incorrectly) thinking that the child would inherit the pid property and could be referred to by `this.pid`, but it cannot.

Is there a way to do this without hardcoding the pid value?

I know I could do `parent.child.cid = parent.pid + '_child_789'` after creating the object but that is not scalable or practical for me.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access properties like that in your object literal. I would go into more detail, however, this question has already been answered several times. Please review the following questions:

[JavaScript: Access own Object Property inside Array Literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330686/javascript-access-own-object-property-inside-array-literal)

[Can a JavaScript object property refer to another property of the same object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173610/can-a-javascript-object-property-refer-to-another-property-of-the-same-object)