# how to detect a function was called with javascript

Tags: javascript, aop

I have a javascript function.

How to check:

- if function was called ( in `<head></head>` section have this function), then not to call the function
- if function was not called ( in `<head></head>` section haven't this function), then call the function

like `require_once` or `include_once` with **PHP**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you find out the caller function in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Static variables**

Here's how to create static (like in C) variables using self calling functions to store your static variables in a closure.

```
var myFun = (function() {
  var called = false;
  return function() {
    if (!called) {
      console.log("I've been called");
      called = true;
    }
  }
})()
```

**Abstract the idea**

Here's a function that returns a function that only gets called once, this way we don't have to worry about adding boiler plate code to every function.

```js
function makeSingleCallFun(fun) {
  var called = false;
  return function() {
    if (!called) {
      called = true;
      return fun.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }
}

var myFun = makeSingleCallFun(function() {
  console.log("I've been called");
});

myFun(); // logs I've been called
myFun(); // Does nothing
```

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd At the begining i thought that `callee` was a typo about `called` function name, but it's a variable and does match, so I don't really know why was downvoted. Did u try the code before commenting?

Comment: @erm3nda no idea. this is 4 years ago

Answer (score 13):

Use decorator pattern.

```
// your function definition
function yourFunction() {}

// decorator
function callItOnce(fn) {
    var called = false;
    return function() {
        if (!called) {
            called = true;
            return fn();
        }
        return;
    }
}

yourFunction(); // it runs
yourFunction(); // it runs    
yourFunction = callItOnce(yourFunction);
yourFunction(); // it runs
yourFunction(); // null
```

This solution provides a side-effect free way for achieving your goal. You don't have to modify your original function. It works nice even with library functions. You may assign a  new name to the decorated function to preserve the original function.

```
var myLibraryFunction = callItOnce(libraryFunction);
myLibraryFunction(); // it runs
myLibraryFunction(); // null
libraryFunction(); // it runs
```

Comment: Oh no, I skipped your answer, and added an answer that is almost the same. I'll leave my answer since I also showed a different way. However, how is this the decorator pattern? I think this is more like aspect oriented programming.

Comment: @Juan you are both right, AOP often uses the decorator pattern

Comment: Also called function composition 

Answer (score 5):

```
var called = false;
function blah() {
   called = true;
}

if ( !called ) {
   blah();
}
```

Comment: For those global-variable-nazis [since this is in the global scope], you can use blah.called instead of var blah... assuming blah is already defined.  This code is pretty enough for me, though.

Comment: The disadvantage of this pattern is that you have to wrap the function call in a conditional statement everywhere it gets invoked.

Comment: @ItzWarty This is not pretty enough for me, as Török Gábor pointed out. There's a reason globals are bad, so I avoid them like the plague, call me a global-nazi! Plenty of other examples here that don't use a global variable and don't require wrapping the call with a conditional everywhere it's called

Answer (score 4):

You can use a global variable in a custom namespace to store whether the function has been called.

```
if(!window.mynamespace){
    window.mynamespace={};
}

mynamespace.callMeOnlyOnce=function(){

    if(mynamespace.alreadyCalled)return;

    alert('calling for the first time');
    mynamespace.alreadyCalled=true;
};

// alert box comes
mynamespace.callMeOnlyOnce();


// no alert box
mynamespace.callMeOnlyOnce();
```

Comment: The `this` value refers to the Global object, not to the function itself, and `allreadyCalled` will end up being a property of the Global object. This is because the function has been invoked from a reference that doesn't have a base object: `callMeOnlyOnce();`. [More info on `this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320677/this-operator-in-javascript/3320706#3320706)

Answer (score 1):

```
If (!your_func.called) {
    your_func.called = true;
    your_func();
}
```

Comment: Out of all the answers, this is the one that requires the most repetition of code. Every call needs to set the flag and be wrapped with a conditional.

Comment: This works, thanks for answering. I was stuck for more than 2 months and you helped me, your code works like a charm.

Comment: @Juan Mendes Repetition of code? That's a problem? Make a wrapper function with a function name as a parameter. I've described here only an idea.