# Javascript call only once a child function with setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call myfun1 only once with setInterval. I want to avoid using a global variable. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332265/how-to-detect-a-function-was-called-with-javascript) but it does not work (just calls the function every 2000 ms). Naturally I need to call main() every 2000 ms.

```
(function($){         
    setinterval(main,2000);  

     function main (){            
        if(/*condition*/) return;

        function callItOnce(fn) {
            var called = false;
            return function() {
                if (!called) {
                    called = true;
                    return fn();
                }
                return;
            }
        }

        myfun1 = callITOnce(myfun1);
        myfun1();

        function myfun1(){/*code*/};
        function myfun2(){/*code*/};
        function myfun3(){/*code*/};
})(jquery);
```

Comment: You defined the function `callItOnce` and then used the function `callOnce`.

Comment: If you only want it invoked once, why are you using `setInterval`?

Comment: Because I'm checking other stuff dynamically, need it that way.

Comment: Does that particular part of the function need to be inside of setinterval since you are only calling it once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a flag :

```
(function($){ 
    var timer = setInterval(main,2000), ran=true;

    function main() {
        if(/*condition*/) return;

        if (ran) { //runs when ran=true, which is only the first time
            myfun1();
            ran = false;  //since it's set to false here
        }

        function myfun1(){/*code*/};
        function myfun2(){/*code*/};
        function myfun3(){/*code*/};

})(jquery);​
```

Comment: it looks like OP is trying to perform more than one function within the `main` function. I had the same initial knee-jerk reaction, but I don't think that this is necessarily the correct answer.

Comment: @adeno: OP wants to execute everything else inside `main` all the time, except for the call to `myfun1` which OP only wants to execute once.

Comment: Correct! Thanks for understanding

Comment: +1. I just fixed the syntax errors in the sample code so it can execute. See working DEMO here: http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/aWWay/

Answer (score 0):

The `callItOnce` function you wrote should work. You just need to declare the function outside the `setInterval` call. Otherwise it gets redefined each time.

```
(function () {

function myfun1(){/*code*/};
function myfun2(){/*code*/};
function myfun3(){/*code*/};

function callItOnce(fn) {
    var called = false;
    return function() {
        if (!called) {
            called = true;
            return fn();
        }
        return;
    }
}

myfun1 = callItOnce(myfun1);

function main() {
    if(/*condition*/) return;
    myfun1();
}

setInterval(main, 2000);

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to work around this is to use a variable on the function itself.

```
function myFunc1(){

if(arguments.callee.done){return;}


arguments.callee.done = true;    

}
```

This way the "done" variable on the method myFunc1 would make sure the method is executed only once.

Answer (score -1):

setInterval returns a value that you can pass to clearInterval to stop the callback from being called.

```
var i = 0;
var timeout_id = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(i);
    if(i >= 5){ clearTimeout(timeout_id) }
    i++;
})
```

Comment: That's another option, but I want to call only myFun1() once, others with the interval...

Comment: @missingno: This will stop the callback altogether. OP seems to want the callback to continue but not execute `func1` inside it more than once.