# check if sitecatalyst / Omniture s.t() has been called

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-analytics, adobe-analytics

I want to to check if the s.t() or page load has already been called on a site.  I control when it gets called, but I want a very generic way to ask if it has already been called.  The main purpose is to either call s.t() or s.tl() depending on what has previously happened.

Answer (score 4):

This will return true if the SiteCatalyst code has fired.

```
(function(){for(w_m in window)if(w_m.substring(0,4)=='s_i_'&&window[w_m].src)if(window[w_m].src.indexOf('/b/ss/')>=0)return!0;})()
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I do not know when this was introduced to AppMeasurement and I did not find any documentation about it but I accidentially found the following two callback functions that we use successfully to identify the moment shortly before and after the tracking request.

```
s.registerPreTrackCallback(function() {
    console.log('Pre-Track');
});

s.registerPostTrackCallback(function() {
    console.log('Post-Track');
});
```

Comment: Those appear to still be useful today. Search the web for "Adobe analytics registerPreTrackCallback" and you will see the latest documentation for it.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332265/how-to-detect-a-function-was-called-with-javascript) gives the concept behind it- before firing either function, check if the other was already fired. For example:

```
s.pageName="page";
s.eVar1="value";

if(!linkFired) {
  var pageFired=true;
  s.t();
}
if(!pageFired) {
  var linkFired=true;
  s.tl(this,'o','custom link');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will actually give you any answers but you could also overwrite the s.t function with something like:

```
s.AltSt = s.t;

s.t = function (vo) {
    s.AltSt(vo);
    console.log("Do your own stuff!");
}
```

Haven't 100% tested this but on first observation this should work..

Answer (score 0):

you could wait to see if s is called

```
setTimeout(function checkIfsLoad() {
    if (typeof s == 'object') {
        doYourStuff();
    } else {
        setTimeout(checkIfsLoad,150);
    }
}, 150);
```