# How do I know when a function was called in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I don't know when a function was called. I'm trying to change the text of a p element with an id of downloads, that I know how to do. But how do you figure out when a function was called? The function is named move. Something like this? I just need when a function was called. Maybe an event listener?

```
    if (move.wasCalled) {
        // Some code
    }
```

Comment: If you did a google search, you would've saved yourself time rather than writing this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332265/how-to-detect-a-function-was-called-with-javascript

Comment: Do you want to execute some code _every time_ the function called - if yes, insert the code inside the function - or do you want to know if a function called?

Comment: Do you want 'when' or 'if' function was called? 'when' ---> new Date().getTime() then update a global scope var with this time whereas 'if' ---> use a Boolean flag, set global scope var to true when func called

Comment: I did do a google search.

Comment: I want to know if a function was called

Comment: I voted to reopen this as the dupe was not exact, although the title suggested that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to detect a function was called with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332265/how-to-detect-a-function-was-called-with-javascript)

Comment: @RezaSaadati No, that quastion doesn't have the answer i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if you want to add an eventlistener for when move is called:

```
 move = (function(old) {
     var handlers = [];
     function move() {
        old.apply(this, arguments);
        handlers.forEach(function(handler) { handler(); });
     }
     move.wasCalled = function(handler) { handlers.push(handler) };
     return move;
   };
})(move);
```

So you can use it as:

```
 move.wasCalled(function() {
   //...
 });

 move();
```

---

If you however want to determine synchronously if the function was added already, just set a property when move was called, it can be rewritten as:

```
move = (old => (...args) => {
  move.wasCalled = true;
  old(...args);
})(move);
```

---

Or for older environments:

```
move = (function(old) { 
  return function() {
    move.wasCalled = true;
    old.apply(null, arguments);
  };
})(move);
```

So now

```
 if(move.wasCalled) { /*...*/ }
```

actually works

Comment: Whats args? And what should be before args? Sorry, I'm kind of a noob at js

Comment: @sadieKoe if you add this code block after the declaration of `function move() { }` and before you call it the first time, the `move.wasCalled` will be set. Now `(...args)` takes all arguments that are passed to the function that replaces the original function and will then call the original function with that, so `move(1,2,3)` will still work

Comment: When i put it in the code, it gives an error, "Unexpected token >"

Comment: I just did! Sorry!

Comment: @sadieKoe no worries, its just that a 2 year old version is likely to be vulnerable to a lot of attacks, so its not just that newer code won"t work its also a security thing

Comment: Ok. Thanks for telling me that.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the ... for? Also, I got an error, "Unexpected token >"

Comment: @sadieKoe okay then forget about your browser, its KhanAcademys fault. They didn't expect that you would write new code :). I added a version that should work there

Comment: Thank you so much! But for some reason, its not doing anything. I added a `console.log("Hi");`, but nothing happened

Comment: You still here?

Comment: I did this. `if (move.isCalled) { console.log("Hi"); }`, but nothing happened

Comment: Hello! You here?

Comment: I think you are actually looking for some kind of event listener, but thats hard to tell. I guess its the best if you just continue your course without this, and get back here at a later point, then we can continue this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `console.log("move function was called.");` inside the if statement move.wasCalled like this:

```
if (move.wasCalled) {
    // Some code
    console.log("move function was called.");
}
```

So when the if statement is executed it will be logged in the console e.g.

> Check in the Google Chrome dev tools console tab.