# this keyword in a class method

Tags: javascript

```
var mC = function(map){
    var init = function(iMap){
        alert("Init " + this + " with");
    }
    init(map);
};
var m = new mC({});
```

why i am getting value of this as [object window]? Is it a window object??

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320677/this-operator-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Because `init` is a variable of `mC`, it will share its scope (which currently is the global scope, which is also the `window` object).

However. If you changed to the following:

```
var mC = function(map){
    this.init = function(iMap){
        alert("Init " + this + " with");
    }
    this.init(map);
};
var m = new mC({});
```

Then `this` inside `init` would be a reference to your instance.

Comment: It's about how the function is invoked, e.g. `init();`, has no *base object* (is not bound as a property of any accessible object), so the `this` value within it will point to the global object, no matter where in the *scope* chain you are.

Answer (score 1):

It's because init is not a "class method" - it's a function you're defining and calling inside a constructor. That doesn't make it special of other functions in any way.

You will need to call the init function in the context of the mC function's 'this':

```
init.call(this);
```

Or, you will need to make 'init' a member of this or this.prototype, which will automatically use the object it's a member of as 'this'

You may want to google about JavaScript's this keyword if this confuses you :)

Answer (score 1):

What else would you be expecting to get?

You defined init as a function and then called it in the global space so that is why you got what you did. You didn't attach it to the mC class.