# callback function return global object :/

Tags: javascript, prototype, callback

Please help with my problem described below:

```
var Land = function(){
    this.cities = [];
}
Land.prototype = {
    addCity : function(city){
        this.cities.push(city);
    }
}
var City = function(){
    this.val = "foo";
};
City.prototype = {
    test : function(){
        this.val = "bar";
        console.log(this);
    }
}


var myLand = new Land();
myLand.addCity(new City());

// this row return right - City Object - :)
myLand.cities[0].test();

function callBack(fnc){
    fnc();
}

// this row return fail - global object - :(
// i need return City Object as in the first case
callBack(myLand.cities[0].test);
​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because your `callback` function invokes the `fnc` parameter directly, and the reference `fnc` doesn't contains any base object (`fnc` is not bound to any accessible object)

There are many ways to avoid this, the most simple IMO, would be to use an anonymous function, and there execute your function:

```
callBack(function () {
  myLand.cities[0].test();
});
```

In that way, the `this` value inside `test` will be the `myLand.cities[0]` object.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320677/this-operator-in-javascript) for more info about the behavior of the `this` value on functions.