# JavaScript OOPS Question

Tags: javascript, closures, scope, instance-variables

A JavaScript newbie here. I have this following code:

```
function testObject(elem) {
    this.test = "hi";
    this.val = elem;
    console.log(this.test+this.val);
    echo();

    function echo () {
        console.log(this.test+this.val);
    }
}

var obj = new testObject("hello");
```

When it is run, I expect "hihello" to be outputted twice in the console. Instead it outputs as expected the first time but returns NaN the second time.

I'm sure I'm missing something here. I thought that the internal function can access the vars held outside. Can someone please guide me? I'm more of a functional UI developer and don't have much experience with OO code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that inside `echo` the `this` value points to the global object, and `this.test` and `this.val` (which are referring to `window.test` and `window.val`) are `undefined`.

You can set the `this` value of echo by invoking it like:

```
echo.call(this);
```

That happens because you were invoking the function by `echo();`, then the `this` value is implicitly set to the global object.

Give a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320677/this-operator-in-javascript/) to learn how the `this` value works.

**Edit:** For being able to calling just `echo();` you should persist the `this` value from the outer function context, there are a lot of ways to do it, for example:

```
//...
var instance = this; // save the outer `this` value
function echo (){
  console.log(instance.test+instance.val); // use it
}
echo();
//...
```

Or

```
//...
var echo = (function (instance) {
  return function () {
    console.log(instance.test+instance.val);
  };
})(this); // pass the outer `this` value
echo();
//...
```

Comment: I think I'm getting the idea. What if the echo function takes parameters as well? echo("sometext").call(this) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Newbie: You can simply pass them after the first argument of `call`, e.g. `echo.call(this, 'arg1', 'arg2');`

Comment: Thanks, this works but this also means that I'll have to change each and everyone of my function calls. Any way I can modify the function declaration itself to make it work? Thanks again!

Comment: @Newbie, to simply call `echo();` you should persist the `this` value from the outer function, I've added two exapmles...

Answer (score 3):

You could also do this:

```
function testObject(elem) {
    this.test = "hi";
    this.val = elem;
    console.log(this.test+this.val);

    this.echo = function () {
        console.log(this.test+this.val);
    }
    this.echo();
}

var obj = new testObject("hello");
```

​Whenever you call `this.echo()` or `obj.echo()`, `this` will be bound to the object invoking the function.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find it elegant to declare class methods like this:

```
function testObject(elem) {
    this.test = "hi";
    this.val = elem;
    this.echo();
}

testObject.prototype = {
    echo: function () {
        console.log(this.test + this.val);
    }
}

var obj = new testObject("hello");
```