# Access class members from nested functions

Tags: javascript, oop

i have this class in javascript

```
var MyGird = Class.extend({
  classMemeber1 : "Some Value"
  ,clickEvent : function(){
        this.editor.on({
            afteredit: function() {
                //
                //  HOW TO I ACCESS classMemeber1 from here? ?
                //
                //
            }
        })
})
```

how do i access classMemeber1 from inside of afteredit...
Thanks

Comment: What JS framework are you using?  Looks like what you're doing here is more complex than I thought.

Comment: Extjs but this a class that wraps Extjs Grid

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to save a reference to the object invoking `clickEvent` function by storing `this` <sup>[1]</sup> in a variable. It will be available inside the `afteredit` method because of *closure*.

```
var MyGird = Class.extend({
    classMemeber1: "Some Value",
    clickEvent: function () {
        var self = this; // save object reference
        this.editor.on({
            afteredit: function () {
                // access classMemeber1 from here
                // by using the stored reference
                alert(self.classMemeber1);
            }
        });
    },
    // ...
});
```

<sup>[1] [this operator in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320677/this-operator-in-javascript/3320706#3320706) (note: *'this'* is not an operator)</sup>

Comment: I am new to JavaScript. Your answer saved me lot of trouble :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 10):

If you write ES6, you can use arrow functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

In your example, should be something like (not tested):

```js
var MyGird = Class.extend({
    classMemeber1: "Some Value",
    clickEvent: () => {
        this.editor.on({
            afteredit: () => () {
                alert(this.classMemeber1);
            }
        });
    },
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it using a library call `cron`.

this library allows you to schedule tasks very easily
here is an example of code i used to implement sending a message at a specific time

```
import {CronJob} from "cron";

sendMessageEveryMinute(message) {
    let bot = this.bot;
    let chatId = this.chatId;
    let job = new CronJob('1 * * * * *', 
        function () {
            bot.telegram.sendMessage(chatId, message).then(r => console.log(r));
    }, null, true, 'Europe/Rome');
}
```

as you can see (minus the telegram methods) what we do is just declare an object called `CronJob` which takes as input the so called ***cron schedule expressions*** (which is used to define the actual time when the function we want to execute will  execute) and the second parameter is the function itself we want to execute at that specific time.
The `true` param that you see is telling that the schedule will start at instantiation time. this means that the schedule will start as the object `job` gets instantiated.
For the other params look at the documentation:
[cron documentation](https://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)