# JavaScript 'this' confusion

Tags: javascript, object, this

This is probably pretty easy, yet I am confused, so maybe I might still learn something more today. I am trying to do the following:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.src = {}
myObj.src.A = ['1.png','2.png','3.png'];
myObj.A = new Image();
myObj.A.src = this.src.A[0];
```

This will result in an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'A' of undefined` error.
When I use `myObj.src.A[0]` instead of `this` it is working fine.

What would be the correct way to use this in this context?

Comment: "What would be the correct way to use this in this context?" you should show us what is your context...

Comment: What do you expect `this` to refer to, and why?  From the code you posted the one thing I can tell you it *won't* be is "myObj".

Comment: Why do you think `this` should refer to `myObj`? You should read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this. From the code you posted it does not look like you need to use `this` at all.

Comment: @FelixKling Kind of true :) Got it now, I somehow thought I could use it just like inside a `myObj.f = function(){this.g = 55;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` keyword is always different depending on the scope involved. In the code snippet you've posted above, assuming that you're just putting this in the document somewhere in the head, `this` refers to the page itself. So, it's fairly obvious at that point that `this.src.A` will be undefined. If you were to apply an event to it with a delegate such as:

```
myObj.click = function() {
    alert(this.src.A[0]);
}
```

The `this` keyword receives a new scope belonging to the owner of the delegate (in this case myObj). `this` is very easy to track so long as your clearly define your scopes and your scope boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

`this` refers to the object context in which the code is executing. So if an object has a method `aMethod`, then inside `aMethod` `this` references the object that owns it.

I'm assuming your code there is running in the global namespace, so `this` is undefined. Really you just want `myObj.A.src = myObj.src.a[0];`.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Answer (score 1):

`this` does not refer to `var myObj` in the case of your code. It is likely that if you are not inside the scope of a function or an objects method then `this` is referring to the [DOM window](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) which has no attribute `src.A`

Answer (score 1):

`this` in JavaScript depends heavily on the context in which a function is called. If your code is (as it looks to be above) just hanging out in a script tag in the page, then `this` is going to be the "global" context -- which in the browser is the `window` object.

Generally, `this` refers to the object/scope a function belongs to, but there's a number of special (and useful) cases that happen because functions are first class values that can be assigned to different objects and invoked in various contexts.

Some lengthy elaboration others have written might be helpful:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3320706/87170
- http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/fully-understanding-the-this-keyword/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/this_Operator

It can seem a little tricky at the start, particularly if you're used to languages in which `this` is *always* one thing, but after you learn a few rules it becomes fairly straightforward and actually very useful.

Answer (score -1):

`myObj.src.A[0]` would be correct in this context because `this` references its immediate parent.

Comment: *`this` references its immediate parent*... whose parent? There is not such an relationship between "function context" and local variables.

Comment: `this`'s parent. It's relative. =)

Comment: Ah, I just realized why you were confused by that. Horrible explanation of a very simple concept which was not even close to what I was intending. My fault. Disregard.