# When is "this" evaluated?

Tags: javascript, this

For the following piece of code

```
a.b = function c(){
    return function e(){
        return this;
    };
};
d = a.b();
```

What will the value of d() be? This might not be a very good example, but I am just confused about what "this" will refer to.

Thanks,

Comment: you could try doing console.log(this); inside the function

Comment: My vote would be "at execution time".

Comment: This question has almost been asked as many times as how to parse HTML with regex (lol). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320677/this-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

Seeing as d will now equal a FUNCTION, "this" will be evaluated to whatever function calls it. It hasn't actually been evaluated yet.

At the end of execution, `d='function e() { return this; }'`, so the moment you execute `d()` is when `this` will be evaluated.

Comment: But in this case `this` will be evaluated to `window` when `d()` is called.

Comment: Exactly, WHEN `d()` is finally evaluated, but you're right. The reason this is the case as everything that isn't a child of an object is a child of the window, so think of `d()` as `window.d()`, hence why this refers to the window.

Answer (score 1):

From your code d is not the same as the "this". d will be a the function e, since you are setting d to be return value of the function call a.b() which returns a function, so

```
d = function e(){
    return this;
}
```

Now the value of `this` depends upon how you call this function d. `this` will be evaluated when this function is called. If you just call it like  `d()` `this` will be the global `Window` Object.

and lets say if I have

```
obj ={foo:1, bar:2};
```

and I call like this

```
d.call( obj )
```

`this` will be the object obj. the call() method is used to call a function on any object, the passed object behaves as `this` inside that function.

I know Javascript this is really confusing and it isn't easy to get your head around it.
May be this can help http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`this` is an implicit parameter to all functions.

See [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

If you know python, `this` is just like `self`, but not explicitly written and always there

Answer (score 0):

this is normally the caller of a function

```
$('.image').each(function(index){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
}
```

I think a.b() will return a

see http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `d()` was called immediately after the last line of your snippet `d()` will return the global object: `window` if you're in a browser.

However both of these are true:

```
d.call(a) === a;
d.call(a.b.prototype) === a.b.prototype;
```

which is to say that `this` is defined by what is passed in as the first argument to `call`.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a reference to the object on which method was called.
`d()` is similar `window.d()` (if there is no `with` instruction)