# Function object, context and this

Tags: javascript, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [this operator in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320677/this-operator-in-javascript)

The term *context* is bit confusing me.If i declare a function within a function i.e nested function and execute there itself,like below...

```
function  foo(){
    function fo(){
    alert(this);
       }
    fo();
   }
```

the *this* keyword should point to the function object rather than *window* since function fo() is within its parent function.Since function is also an javascript object,than why the this keyword is traversing the function object and pointing to window?
Also this keyword points to the current object on which the function operates ,so function object is the object on which the nested function operates.

Comment: The context of `this` depends on **how** you call the function not on the function itself.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is. Here is a reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Oh yay!  Another javasrcipt `this` question.  There are over 500,000 very similar questions on SO already.  ...surely one of these addresses your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search-new?q=javascript+this+

Comment: I'm too lazy to answer this question, but try `new fo()` and you'll see what's happening and eventually figure out how context works in JS.

Comment: @elclanrs i m really getting confused ,if context is an object on which function operates than parent function is also an javascript object within which the nested function operates

Comment: @elclanrs how can i do new fo() since fo() is the nested function

Comment: Correction, `new foo()`, see @dlutxx and I's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If you just call `foo()` in the top level, it is identical to `window.foo()`.
And `window` is the actual `context` of foo, so, `this` points to the `window` object.

Comment: but the keyword this is within the fo() but not within foo

Comment: Seems you have a little misunderstanding of `context` here:
The context is the object to which your current running code is attached to, not the `Function` the code is running in. @Maizere Pathak

Comment: i m really getting confused ,if context is an object on which function operates than parent function is also an javascript object within which the nested function operates

Comment: Edit made with, more info for you.

Comment: @rounce: rolled back edit. "when a function is called (ie. foo()), this is scoped to object which this points to when it's called." is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what dlutxx said. If you have a function (in the global space) and you simply call it like `foo()` the context is the window itself (since the function is a member of the window object). However, if you use the `new` keyword for getting a new instance of the function, `this` will refer to the function object.

```
function foo() {
    alert(this);
}

foo(); // "this" inside the function will be window

new foo(); // "this" inside the function will be the function object.
```

If you want to have a custom value for `this` inside the function, you can call it using `.call()` like:

```
foo.call(x); // "this" inside the function will be x
```

---

Example code for your case:

```
function  foo(){
    function fo(){
        alert(this);
    }
    fo(); // "this" is window
    new fo(); // "this" is the function object
    fo.call('x'); // "this" is 'x'
}
```

Comment: u r not concentrating in my question ,watch the code i have provided

Answer (score 1):

If you randomly use `this` inside of a function which is NOT a constructor, then you will get one of a few different results:

```
function callThis () { return this; }


callThis(); // returns window object

var Bob = { func : callThis };

Bob.func(); // returns Bob

callThis.call(Bob);  // returns Bob
```

Call is a method which is used to determine the context of the call.
If the call's context can not be determined by:

a. What's in front of the "." (`Bob.func();`)
b. What's explicitly passed into `.call()`, `.apply()` or `.bind()`

Then it's set to `window`.

That is how context is resolved.

So if you have a specific object in mind for `this`, then your solutions are as follows:

```
function objMethod () {
    var self = this;
    function doStuff () {
        self.otherFunc();
        self.otherProperty = "bob";
    }

    doStuff();
}


var myObj = { myMethod : objMethod };
myObj.myMethod();
```

`myObj` calls `objMethod` with the context set to `myObj`.
`objMethod` saves a reference to the current context (`myObj`) as `self`. `doStuff` uses the reference to modify the properties of the referenced object.

```
function outer () {
    function inner () { this.property = "Bob"; }
    inner.call(this);
}


var obj = {};
outer.call(obj);
```

Here, `outer` is passed a context, using `.call()`.
Then `inner` is passed the `this` of `outer`, again, using `.call()`

```
var bob = { name : "Bob" };

function sayName () { console.log(this.name); }

var bobFunc = sayName.bind(bob);
bobFunc();
```

Here, we use `.bind()` to create a version of sayName where `this` is always set to `bob`.
You can feel free to mix and match these systems all you'd like (and when dealing with async programming, you likely will).

Answer (score 0):

my understanding is that although `function fo()` is defined in the scope of `function foo()`, which means that it is not accessible from outside of `foo` unless you return it, the rules that apply to the value of `this` when you call this internal function, are still the same as if you called any other function.

```
function f() {
    function g() {
        console.log(this)
    }
    console.log(this);
    g();
    g.apply(this);
    }

f()           // => Window, Window, Window
f.apply(this) // => Window, Window, Window
f.apply({})   // => Object, Window, Object
```

Comment: yaa this sounds better than others post

Comment: I have added sample code that demonstrates the behaviour